# Haskell preorder traversal of binary tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

I'm trying to write a function that will traverse a binary tree and return a list of the integers encountered. 
My data Tree declaration is as follows:

```
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf Int
   deriving (Eq,Show)
```

My first idea was to start the function off with:

```
preorder :: Tree -> [a]  --take in tree, return list of ints
```

But I've seen some people solving this problem online by using a function declaration format similar to:

```
preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree -> [c]
```

And I don't really understand what this line is doing, is it taking multiple inputs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the underlying definition of the tree. They might be using another tree definition, a common one is like:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf b | Branch a (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
```

So they might need to get functions that map values of type `a` and `b` to the type `c`. As your tree definition only has elements of type `Int`, it would suffice for the `preorder` function to be of type `Tree -> [Int]`.

**UPDATE:**

If you want a generalization of your trees in the type of their elements, you can declare this datatype:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

and with this definition, you can define the type of the `preorder` function as follows:

```
preorder :: Tree a -> [a]
```

Comment: ok, so far after the declaration of my function I have this line: "   preorder (Leaf n) = [n]  "  covering the case in which my tree only has one node, in which case the function will return a list containing only that int.  Then I have the line " preorder (Node n l r) = [n] ++ preorder l ++ preorder r  " trying to combine lists and recursively call the function

Comment: Do I need to specify the list this function returns more?  With these three lines currently I get an error saying "  Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’  "

Comment: Yes, because your type `a` isn't bounded in your definition, as your trees do not have elements of arbitrary types but elements of type `Int`, so you have to address the type I gave you in the answer: `preorder :: Tree -> [Int]`.

Comment: The story would be different if your tree datatype was generalized like this: `data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`. There you'd have trees that could be of any type (not only ints, but of type `a`), so you can instantiate your `Int` trees with the datatype `Tree Int`.

Comment: What was "subyacent" supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get my function working perfectly. I understand now why it didn't work, because I needed to specify my return types better, and how to format a recursive call combining multiple lists.

Comment: @Martin if this question has helped you, please consider marking it as solved, thanks!